# Separating unit test from accessibility tests

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm building a React Application using create-react-app and the CI/CD process fails randomly while running accessibility tests.  I would like to seperate the test into unit test and accessibility tests so I can run them at different times with set different parameters. I've tried a number of variations using testMatch etc but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions?

**Unit Test**
`.test.tsx`

**Accessibility test**
`.a11y.test.tsx`

**Path:** `package.js`

```
{
  "name": "MyAPP",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test .test.tsx !.a11y.test.tsx",
    "test:a11y": "react-scripts test .a11y.test.tsx !.test.tsx"
  },
  "jest": {
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you change the naming convention of the a11y test files like - <someName>.test.a11y.ts. With that test default regex won't conflict.

Comment: It doesn't appear register that it's a test. @user1672994